# scala pattern matching to drop some cases

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

With Scala 2.12, I am looping an array with pattern matching to create a new array as below.

```
val arrNew=arrText.map {
  case x if x.startsWith("A") =>x.substring(12, 20)
  case x if x.startsWith("B") =>x.substring(21, 40)
  case x => "0"
}.filter(_!="0")
```

If an element matches one of the two patterns, a new element is added into the new array `arrNew`. Those that do not match will be dropped. My codes actually loop `arrText` twice with filter. If I do not include `case x =>"0"`, there will be errors complaining some elements are not getting matched. Are the codes below the only way of looping just once? Any way I can loop only once with `case` matching?

```
map { x =>
      if (condition1) (output1)
      else if (condition2) (output2)
    }
```

Comment: You should not be using `Arrays`, they are not real collections, they are mutable, they are invariant, they have a by-reference `equals` instead of by-value, etc. -Second, the **Scaladoc** is your friend: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `collect`

> [use case] Builds a new collection by applying a partial function to all elements of this sequence on which the function is defined.

```scala
val arrNew=arrText.collect {
  case x if x.startsWith("A") =>x.substring(12, 20)
  case x if x.startsWith("B") =>x.substring(21, 40)
}
```